# unitн creates an extra clone on stage

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

added a tilemap to the scene, and for some reason there are two of them, there is only one in the inspector, but if you move the coordinates, then there will be another map on the background and for some reason the character was also cloned, what could be the problem?

I thought maybe the link to the prefab was wrong or it was added to the stage in the wrong way, but everything seems to be right

```
int MapNumber = GameState.currentRoom;
        Tilemap map = GridsMap[MapNumber].GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        CurrentMap = Instantiate(map);
        CurrentMap.transform.position = Anchor;
```

Comment: I guess it's because you have 2 cameras, you haven't configured their masks.

Comment: As shingo said it seems that one is rendered through the `MainCamera` and the other one comes from the `UICamera` .. you will need to disable the according layer on your UI camera

Comment: really, while I removed it and everything works fine, I added it for the future on ui, but then I'll think about other options, thanks